# What is the magnitude of the curl of a electric field? and in general from a vectorial field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, differentiation, vector-fields, dielectric

I found the following result in a book:

[image]

but I do not understand what is the meaning of the magnitude of the curl of a vectorial field? and how is this related with the amount of spatial oscillations.

Comment: *I do not understand what is the meaning of the magnitude of a vectorial field.* Do you understand what the  magnitude of a single vector is?

Comment: @G. Smith It was a typo, sorry. I have corrected and edited the question. Thanks. I do understand what is the magnitude of a single vector.

Comment: Do you understand what the magnitude of a vector field is? If so, the curl of a vector field is just *another* vector field.

Comment: Yes, the curl of the vector field is just another vector field. So the magnitude of the vector field would give us the magnitude of every single vector inside the vector field. But then how does this connects with the spatial oscillations from the vector field E?